# my lxde login window has no my login name

Tags: xorg, desktop-environments, lxde, lxsession

just three random names which i have never seen before.

I cant login now, but can login tty. how can i save this?[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can probably type your name by clicking on that `More ...` menu entry